# Stable club economy

Tags: football-manager-2008

I'm managing a decent club (Palermo - Italy) and having lot of trouble with economy (like minus $60M). I had the same problem in a lot of clubs.

Is there anyway to improve this?

Some info:

1. I **always** sell more that I buy.
2. The club is ok with my salaries management.
3. I'm almost in the best 8 teams in all competitions, UCL, Serie A, National Cup.

Comment: This is quite an old game, so it may be hard to get sufficient attention to get good answers to this question. With that said, even if your salary management is fine, it doesn't mean that the **club's** is. They give you a budget to spend, and you should do your best not to go over it. It doesn't mean that it won't cost the club money, it still will be costly. You have to raise funds to **cover what you spend on salaries, along with other expenses**.

Comment: If you are lucky enough, the society will be sold to a new property that will cover all the debts. That happened to me when I was playing with a SerieC2 team which had a ridiculous stadium with poor earnings.

Comment: Are your loses increasing despite transfer market profits?

Comment: @camelCase Exactly! I bought 15 players, all free (not contract) and sell some players for a total of $50M. And still got deficit. I just checked out and it seems that I spend a lot on "on sign" payment with all those 15 players, but still, the difference is too big to make that a deficit.